# The query not work in version 3

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

first table: id
second table: control_id, number

I have a query that work in version 5 but not work in version 3.
How to select all rows where id of these rows is not present in table 2 and
if is present(the id in table 1 = control_id from table 2) compare by number (for example if number <10)

Something like these

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `a` 
WHERE  b="1" AND c >"0" 
       AND d IN ( SELECT *  FROM   e  WHERE f<"1"  )
       OR  d NOT IN ( SELECT z  FROM  x )
```

error (1064).

You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'SELECT *  FROM   e WHERE f<"'1"  )

### OR d NOT IN ( SELECT z  FROM  x )' at line 2

### ОК

Comment: `( SELECT   FROM   e  WHERE f<"1"  )` ?? which col you select?

Comment: You mean to say MySQL 3.x version or 5.3?

Comment: indentation and represent  still maters

Comment: Version 3? What is version 3?

Comment: version 3.23.38 . No import that col. Problem is in  AND d IN ( SELECT  . I dot know if is possible to do in version 3 Select in select

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `users` 
WHERE  user="1"
       AND user IN ( SELECT   FROM   user  WHERE user<"1"  )
       OR  user NOT IN ( SELECT user  FROM  users )

Error is 1064 - Sql syntax error near 'select from user where user<"1"


Can i use <in> and selecet in select in ver 3.23

Comment: Error (1064).

You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'SELECT *  FROM   e WHERE f<"'1"  )

OR d NOT IN ( SELECT z  FROM  x )' at line 2
---------------------------
ОК   
---------------------------